# How to change Explorer folder template for zip files

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, zip

As we know, Windows 10 allows users to customize folder template by right-clicking for Context Menu -> Properties in Explorer.

If I am not mistaken, the template of a parent folder could also be 'inherited' by new folders created in that parent folder.

Is there a way to customize folder template for zip files in Explorer?

In particular, I am hoping to move the Date Modified column to be following File Name.

Comment: I believe this should be possible through `ps.exe`, but can't remember the specifics off the top of my head.

Comment: @Arctiic: I see. Let me know if something else comes to mind. Thanks!!

Comment: Here's a lead you can look into (the original question I had in mind was deleted *or* I can no longer find the one I'm recalling, which AFAIR had a fairly detailed answer that utilized `ps.exe`):

`"PowerShell one-liner to list Folder types: (gp 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderTypes\*').CanonicalName`
`Saved views are indexed by their Shell namespace path. So 'Desktop\This PC\Docuemts' can have a different view from 'Desktop\This PC\C:\Users_UserName_\Documents'`

— Credit goes to @KeithMiller

Comment: @Arctiic: Nice. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Arctiic: Thanks for the nod. Poking and prodding the registry now...

Comment: Update: The *FolderType* ID for CompressedFolder is `{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}`. But its entry under `HKLM\...\FolderTypes` doesn't have the `TopView` subkey that normally hold the view settings, and I suspect the defaults come from the DLL that handles displaying compressed folders. However,  preliminary testing shows that creating the registry key `...\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}` and associated values will create a custom default view that is applied to newly created zip files.

Comment: Will post an answer tomorrow after a good night's sleep and more testing...

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the way to set a custom template for `.zip` folders is via an `AllFolders` regtistry entry. These can be per-user modifications if created under:

```
    HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
```

or machine-wide if created under:

```
    HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
```

Because the view property bags are strored with binary data specifying Columns, sort, etc., it's best to copy an existing saved view that has been set to the preferred defaults. Locating the bag you want to copy is the only tricky part. You'll be looking for an entry With the registry path:

```
    HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\<Bag#>\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
```

---

### Warning:

For a `.zip` folder to use its dedicated *`FolderType`* (`{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}`), it must be created/opened in a folder that ***does not*** have Inheritance set for itself or any ancestor.

---

[ProcMon](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) is one way to determine what bag is being writeen to when an **Explorer** window is closed (that is when any view modifications are saved). Another way is to:

1. determine the highest numbered bag currently in use.

   - **PowerShell**:

     ```
       'MaxBaag# - {0}' -f ([Int[]]((gci 'HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags' -Name) -match '\d+') | sort)[-1]
     ```
2. Open **Explorer**, create a new `.zip` folder, set its view to your liking, close the **Explorer** window.
3. The view you just created should now be saved with the name <MaxBag# + 1>

Once you've located the bag you want to copy you simply have to:

1. Export the registry key:

   ```
   HKCU\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\<Bag#>\Shell\{80213e82-bcfd-4c4f-8817-bb27601267a9}
   ```
2. Open the `.reg` file and edit the key path:

   - For a per-user mod, simply replace the bag number with the string `AllFolders`
   - For a machine-wide mod, in addition to replacing the bag#, replace:

     - `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software`
   - with:

     - `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE`

       ```
         Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

         ; Copied From:
         ; [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213E82-BCFD-4C4F-8817-BB27601267A9}]
         ; Per-user path
         [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213E82-BCFD-4C4F-8817-BB27601267A9}]
         ; Machine-wide path would be:
         [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags\AllFolders\Shell\{80213E82-BCFD-4C4F-8817-BB27601267A9}]
       ```
3. Save and then merge the modified `.reg` file
4. Verify you've created a registry entry similar to the following (don't forget to refresh the view in RegEdit if already opened):
   [image]
5. Sign out and back in (per-user) or restart (machine-wide) for changes to take effect.