# Is there a way to customize context menu for zip files/folders in Explorer

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, zip, context-menu

Is there a way to customize context menu for zip folders in Explorer in Windows 10?

To clarify: context menu within the Explorer's view of a zip folder/file. NOT for the singular .zip file.

I want to be able to add Open With ... .  I am not particular to associating specific extensions with programs, thought that would be pleasant. Being able to have a menu option for opening all file extensions with Sublime Text would be great.

Comment: Might be related: https://superuser.com/questions/1732094/how-to-change-explorer-folder-template-for-zip-files

Comment: Windows 10 already has Open With right context that works fine with ZIP files. You can often associate what you want when you use Open With.

Comment: @John: not for within a zip file. I'll wordsmith my question a little

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. What you want is general Windows (if available) and not constrained to Windows 10.

Comment: @Argyll, that's not possible, you can't add anything to the context menu inside the Windows ZIP Viewer. You can open the ZIP files with another archive viewer like PeaZip which has an Open With option in its Context Menu (but keep in mind that it's only for preview, as you won't be able to save changes back to a comprassed folder.)

Comment: For many programs, a shortcut in the`Send to  >` context menu works as a universal `Open with...`. That's how I access a hex editor, ResourceHacker, and alaternate text editors. Type `shell:SendTo` in the **Explorer** Address bar to quickly access the folder and add shortcuts.